What limitations would prevent the effective use of a giant heat sink to solve global warming?
In the year 2050, a United Nations summit is held to finally take decisive action to stop global warming. Lobbying by the fossil fuel industry blocked the first proposal to cut emissions. Other proposals like using rockets to increase Earth's orbital radius were also rejected. The only proposal not to be shut down by lobbyists is to vent heat into space using a giant heat sink. (See diagram)

What limitations would prevent the effective use of a giant heat sink to solve global warming?
Here are some concerns I have:

Do heat sinks work in a vacuum? I think the ISS does something like this
This is a really tall structure
This structure is going to need a huge surface area
There is a lot of thermal energy to dissipate
If effective, it could create convection currents that alter the weather
If big enough, it might create a gravitational anomaly
Construction would probably cause material shortages

I'm sure there are many other practical concerns. Feel free to explore the ones I've listed or come up with others.

A large sunshade parked at Lagrange point L1 would be about a million times easier to make and much more effective...

There are a lot of better options. But I am asking why this one is terrible.

It being a million times worse than an obvious solution of reflecting energy makes this question rather pointless. Aerosols in upper atmosphere is even easier to implement than a giant space sunshade.

Problems with your question: (a) If you roll your mouse over [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] you'll find they're mutually exclusive. You're required to delete one of them. (b) Listing your answers and expecting more is prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. (c) Open-ended questions are prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. VTC:NAW per the [help].

Are you aware the staggering amount of energy released into the atmosphere mining, refining and casting the petatons of aluminium/copper? What about it not being able to support its own weight and would slump or the fact it would immediately sink through the crust of the planet? Can you narrow the question to a single problem?

you are talking about a radiator not a heat sink.


With current technology, spacecraft thermal radiators can dissipate about 350 W per square meter. Let's say that with some nifty future technology we can rise that to 500 W per square meter.

The energy imbalance which is the immediate cause of global warming is about 0.9 W per square meter.
(Of course it is not the root cause. The root cause is that we humans are changing the composition of the atmosphere so that is can retain more heat. In the end, Earth will of course find a new thermal equilibrium point, but we humans won't like where it will be.)

Since the radiator (with future technology) can reject 500 W/m² and we need to reject about 0.9 W for each square meter of Earth's surface, it follows that the surface of the radiator will have to be about 1/500 of Earth's surface, or 0.2% of Earth surface, or about 1,000,000 square kilometers (390,000 square miles). That's about 1.4 times the area of Texas.

Building a radiator 1.4 times the area of Texas on top of hundred-kilometer tall pillars is rather impractical.

But building a radiator 1.4 times the area of Texas on top of hundred-kilometer tall pillars is not the really difficult engineering problem. The really difficult engineering problem is collecting the heat from all over the Earth and transporting it to the radiator. The thing is, we are not very good at transporting heat. I have no idea of how to accomplish this, other than building billions of refrigerators and pumping the heat into a network of refrigerant pipes. Billions of kilometers of refrigerant pipes spanning the globe. This is the really impractical thing.



To play the devil's advocate... rather than building just one giant heat sink you could build several smaller ones across the world so you'd be able to gather heat more efficiently. Or... you could create artificial static tornadoes to move the hot air into the upper atmosphere where it would cool down. Fun fact, these are actual proposal to try and terraform venus.

@JuimyTheHyena: Or just build a sunshade and park it at L1. But the question asks what it asks.

The basic problem with this idea is that such a heat sink can only work through "black body radiation." Most heat sinks on earth use the interaction with the air which keeps the heat within the atmosphere. This heat sink can't. The earth is already sending heat out via "black body radiation." Building this structure will not significantly increase sending heat from the planet.

Terminology I will use: What you're describing is a radiator, which is part of any heat rejection system. A heat sink the part of the system where the heat is that you want to radiate. Pair it with a heat pump to take heat from the place you don't want heat and put it in the heat sink. Attach a radiator in good thermal contact with the heat sink and a high region of lower temperature and you get a refrigeration or air conditioning system.
There's nothing wrong in principle with building a heat rejection system instead of reducing insolation or changing atmospheric composition. But the design as proposed is practically unbuildable and not useful even if built.
Critical Design Flaws:
There is no reason to go to space with this structure. Pointing it at a clear patch of sky - especially the night sky, but even blue sky will work - is almost as good. The infinite vastness of interstellar space is the universe's biggest, coldest, highest capacity low temperature reservoir, and all your radiator needs to do to be in thermal contact with it is to shine its infrared light in that direction.
Just putting a big radiator up won't help if it's illuminated by sunlight. Heat exchangers work both ways. We also need to thermally insulate from the sun, either by putting it in shadow or by being reflective to visible light (most of the sun's glow is visible) but transparent or black in infrared light (most of the glow of Earth, or anything you can build on Earth, is infrared).
There is no reason to make One Big Structure (and every reason not to, as AlexP describes). Since they don't need to be elevated, you can build little heat rejecters everywhere.
They can be powered and use heat pumps (pump superheated water at high pressure through black pipes at the focus of parabolic mirrors pointed at empty sky) - not a bad solution if you build them next to power plants and power them whenever there is less energy demanded by the grid than energy produced.
Or they can be passive systems (blankets, paint, etc) that are white to visible and black to IR, don't use any heat pump besides weather and Earth's rotation, and don't need any radiator besides whatever patch of earth or sea they're covering.

From my limited understanding one of the big problems which cause the global warming is that the climate active gases in the atmosphere do reflect the heat (infrared). So a radiator that does not extent beyond these gases in the atmosphere would have little use in bringing that energy away from the earth

There are two unavoidable issues.

For a far lower cost, we could just build solar panels and not release the CO2
If you could accomplish this, it wouldn't do anything for the acidification of the oceans, which is what's really going to kill us.


No one has built a building higher as a km until now. Very likely, the costs would be astronomical even in 2050.
Nothing - but I believe, a huge (maybe 1000km x 1000km) white foil in the ocean, immobilized by the same technology as the oil rigs, would do the same.
Goal is to avoid that the sun warms the ocean below it. You will have a cold, uhmm not very living, and dark ocean under the foil. Most importantly, cold.
The global ocean currents would alter a little bit, on a way that the cooling effect would propagate into the whole atmosphere.
